# How not to use raw field names in my query?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm studying PDO and trying to use insert and update queries simpler. I got great answers for my previous question, but they also pointed out that there was serious injection problem in my queries. I've tried figure it out by myself but it didn't go well as I thought. How can i remove the injection problem in these queries? Please help me!

```
function pdoSet($fields, &$values, $source = array()){
$set = '';
$values = array();
if(!$source) $source = &$_POST;
foreach($fields as $field){
    if(isset($source[$field])){
        $set .= " $field =:$field, ";
        $values[$field] = $source[$field];
    }
}
return substr($set, 0, -2);
}

$fields = array(
'name'
, 'part'
, 'tel'
, 'email'
, 'title'
, 'contents'
);

if(!$idx){
    $fields[] = 'reg_date';
    $values[] = 'now()';
    $st = $pdo -> prepare("insert into qna_board set ".pdoSet($fields,   $values));
    $st->execute($values);
}else{
    $st = $pdo -> prepare("update qna_board set ".pdoSet($fields, $values)."   where idx = :idx");
    $st ->bindParam(":idx", $idx);
    $st->execute($values + compact('idx'));
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDO: defining parameters using foreach and $\_POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27702639/pdo-defining-parameters-using-foreach-and-post)

Comment: @davidstrachan it isn't a duplicate, please see my answer

Comment: @MrMarchello The Answer does not need to be an exact duplicate. It shows the user how to build a dynamic query and pass parameters using 'lazy' binding.

Comment: @davidstrachan Well in that case ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first your code does look like it's prone to SQL injection (just as Deceze noted in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28105149/2788532)), however after closer examination I'm quite certain it is safe.

The part that looks troubling is:

```
foreach($fields as $field){
    if(isset($source[$field])){
        $set .= " $field =:$field, ";
        $values[$field] = $source[$field];
    }
}
```

You are dynamically generating the `column => placeholder` pairs and it looks like those values are coming from the `$_POST` superglobal, but they're not. The first parameter you pass to `pdoSet()` is always a hard-coded array, not based on user input which protects you from injection.

As a side note, I would rethink your code design a bit. You said you're only learning PDO (which I applaud, it's a great driver), so here is a very simple OOP snippet that is a bit clearer and one that you can base yourself on:

```
class FooBarBaz
{
    /**
     * @var PDO
     */
    protected $pdo;

    /**
     * @param    string   $index
     * @param    array    $input_values
     * @return   bool
     */
    public function update($index = null, Array $input_values = null)
    {
        if (is_null($input_values))
        {
            $input_values = $_POST;
        }

        $column_list = [
            'name',
            'part',
            'tel',        
            'email',        
            'title',        
            'contents',
        ];

        $placeholders = [];
        $query_values = [];

        foreach ($column_list as $column_name)
        {
            if (array_key_exists($column_name, $input_values))
            {
                $placeholders[] = sprintf('`%s` = :%s', $column_name, $column_name);
                $query_values[$column_name] = $input_values[$column_name];
            }
        }

        if (isset($index))
        {
            $sql = sprintf('UPDATE qna_board SET %s WHERE idx = :idx', implode(',', $placeholders));
            $query_values['idx'] = $index;
        }
        else
        {
            $sql = sprintf('INSERT INTO qna_board SET %s, reg_date = NOW()', implode(',', $placeholders));
        }

        return $this->pdo->prepare($sql)->execute($query_values);
    }
}
```

Also not how I specified the SQL function `NOW()` literally. This is because such a datum must be passed to PDO at parse time ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8704133/2788532)). Note that you should also be checking for errors/exceptions (you should configure PDO to use the latter) and handle them appropriately. A good DBAL will also abstract a lot of the "guts" of PDO away from the programmer, which is a generally good thing (once you practice the basics, of course).